# Windows Phone Test Framework by Expensify

Tags: windows-phone-7, specflow, wp7test

Does the Windows Phone Test Framework by Expensify support testing on real mobile devices running windows phone 7 OS ?
If yes, which devices does it support? Please reply.

Comment: What do you need to test that requires a real device?

Answer (score 4):

It depends what functionality you want to test.

The framework uses 3 different APIs to talk to the apps:

1. a COM API to talk to install/uninstall and start/stop apps
2. Silverlight automation peer support (communicated to using HTTP) to
   talk to the silverlight controls within the apps - this allows get
   and set of values, some list manipulation and inspection of the
   visual tree.
3. Mouse and keyboard emulation to control the emulator
   device - this is needed to do things like physical touches, hard
   button presses (and other emulator interactions when the app isn't
   running - e.g. taking photos).

For devices attached using USB: 1 and 2 are available

For devices attached using a network: 2 only is available

---

In summary, you can do some things if you want to... but I don't use the test framework to test real phones - I stick to the emulator. When external inputs (e.g. camera or gps) are needed then I find a way to mock them

Comment: Hi Stuart!! Thanks for such an early reply. Could you please tell a way to test a PDF Reader application on a windows phone 7.5 real device?? Any framework for automation or any other automation tool ?

Comment: If there was something else... I wouldn't have written the expensify one :) If your app is mainly SL elements, then you can probably use it on the phone for some of your testing. But at this point I think I'd recommend you go for emulator and talk to your customer about why its a good test alternative

Comment: Thanks for the help, Stuart.. I will take your opinion into account and have a discussion with the client.

Comment: Hi Stuart!! From the 3 API's you have mentioned above, only first 2 are supported when device is attached using USB. No support is there for 3rd API ?? Please give your valuable opinion.

Comment: How would any API simulate touch on the screen and on the hard buttons? You'll need Microsoft help or a robot for that... (The guys at LessPainful.com are doing exactly that for Android - I think they have real phones and real robots!)

Comment: @Stuart - Android supports UI automation on physical devices; the lesspainful guys are simply using that.

Comment: @RichardSzalay I understand... although when it comes to orientation switching they told me they had "servos" - but maybe they were pulling my leg :)

Comment: @Stuart - It's possible they actually host the devices in rotatable racks. If so, that's really cool.

Answer (score 0):

according to the first few seconds of http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2JkJfHZDd2g "there is **some** support for devices".

I would hope/expect all devices to devices to behave the same way, subject ot how they're configured.

Comment: Thanks @matt - yes, in my testing most devices do behave 99+% the same - WP7 is nice like that... the only small differences that have started to show are in some speed tests, and I've seen some big differences in GPS performance across phones - bound to happen whenever analog signals come into things